# Divs will not float

Tags: css, html

I been trying every way possible to try and float the sidebar to the left and have it fit beside the content div, but it seems IMPOSSIBLE for me. Please help.

HTML:

```
  <div class="index-page">    

      <img src="images/hosting-header.png" width="458" height="179" alt="Hosting Header">
        <h1> Welcome to Elektrik Host! </h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis 
        egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.
        Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
        placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        <h1> A little about us </h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis 
        egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.
        Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
        placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div><!-- //index-page -->
    <div class="sidebar">

      <img src="images/sidebar-stickers.png" width="150" height="634" alt="Sidebar Stickers">

    </div><!-- //.sidebar -->
```

CSS:

```
.index-page { color: #000; width: 462px; }
.sidebar { float: right; width: 200px; }
```

clearfix :

```
    .clearfix:after {
   content: ".";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Then you're floating it the wrong way, you have `.sidebar {float: right;}` in your mark-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.sidebar { float: left; width: 200px; }` not `right`
2. To make them beside:
      - index-page also need floatleft too `index-page{ float: left;}` (FF need, IE not)

     - move sidebar to before of index-page

Comment: If you leave the `index-page` alone, move the `sidebar` to come first,  give it a `width` and define the `float` and the `index-page` will take care of itself.

Comment: In my test if index-page not have float then it's display below (FF in my case). Oh, IE not need. but FF require @_@

Answer (score 2):

I always find it easier to put the `float`-ing content ahead of the content that makes way for it, so I switched your sidebar to come ahead of the `index-page` div, and used the following CSS:

```
  .sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
  }
```

Demo over at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ekiva3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/index.htm

CSS CODE

```
.floatright { float: right; }
```

HTML CODE

```
<p>
<img class="floatright" src"images/sidebar-stickers.png" width="150" height="634" alt="Sidebar Stickers">
<p>
```

you dont need to do  just apply the class straight to the image.

**PK**